# Use of sed under Mac OS X command line terminal

Tags: html, macos, css, sed, find

I'm trying to use find and sed combined in the terminal for Mac Sierra, but I can't quite get the syntax right. Here's the best I've been able to do so far:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ aschaub$ find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i '' s/"'Lucinda Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', 'DejaVu Sans'"/\"'Arial', 'Helvetica'" /g \;
```

It doesn't fail but it also doesn't work. I'm in the right directory, but when I execute the command, I just the ">" prompt from sed with actually updating my copious HTML files. I know I really should have one .css file with the fonts specified in it, but I inherited some this code and, for the moment, it would just be easier to use find and sed to reset the fonts specified in virtually every HTML file. Thank very much for helping me to debug this. Cheers.

Comment: The ">" prompt usually indicates an unmatched quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

You must enclose your sed command with single quotes, escape `'` in string to replace/replacement string and use `{}` to refer to files found by  the `find` command:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i '' 's/"'\''Lucinda Grande'\'', '\''Lucida Sans Unicode'\'', '\''Lucida Sans'\'', '\''DejaVu Sans'\''"/"'Arial', 'Helvetica'" /g' {} \;
```

Note that this command will replace the whole string `"'Lucinda Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', 'DejaVu Sans'"` with `"'Arial', 'Helvetica'"`, not each listed font.

If you want to replace each font with `'Arial', 'Helvetica'`, you can try this one(while enclosing the sed command with `"`, you don't need to escape all `'`):

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i '' "s/'Lucinda Grande'/'Arial, 'Helvetica'/g;s/'Lucida Sans\( Unicode\)*'/'Arial', 'Helvetica'/g;s/'DejaVu Sans'/'Arial', 'Helvetica'/g" {} \;
```

or if you have GNU sed:

```
find . -name "file" -exec sed "s/\('Lucinda Grande'\|'Lucida Sans\( Unicode\)*'\|'DejaVu Sans'\)/'Arial', 'Helvetica'/g" {} \;
```